# how to post a login to a web form and keep the session -iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsurlrequest

iphone sdk question:  I need to login to a web app and keep the session (session cookie) and then get an xml feed.

I haven't found a good example for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is call:

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]
 setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

and, assuming you're using `NSURLConnection`, it will save any cookies the server sets for you, and regular cookie-based authentication will just work.